# How to test if a value is greater than in flutter test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, flutter-test

I want to check if one value is greater than another value with flutter testing. I know that we can use expect to check if one value is equal to another value.

```dart
expect(valueOne, valueTwo);
```

But how can I check if valueOne is greaterThan valueTwo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you are looking for :
`expect(valueOne, greaterThanOrEqualTo(valueTwo))`

I noticed that flutter community is not very helpful when it comes to writing tests. So if you need any matcher read the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/package-matcher_matcher-library.html). The matcher library is used to match the expected value. We have different methods which you can combine with `expect(value, matcherFunction)` and the unit test should work.